# MS-Access Query Parameter

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to set a parameter to equal a value selected on a form?

For example, I am trying to set my parameter [ComplianceDate] to equal my combobox selected value.

Something like:

```
PARAMETERS [ComplianceDate] DateTime;
[ComplianceDate] = Forms![myForm]![myComboxValue]

SELECT * 
FROM myTable
Where myDate = [ComplianceDate]
```

Comment: Use form reference in place of [ComplianceDate] and remove equality expression after PARAMETERS line.

Comment: If I do that, the SQL wont prompt the user if the user just wants to run the SQL without the form being open.  I am trying to have the sql prompt the user if the query is ran in access directly or use the form value if the form is used.

Comment: That is correct. I never use dynamic parameterized queries. I use VBA to set filter of form or report. Users should not interact with tables and queries, just forms and reports. Input to popup prompts cannot be validated.

Comment: ok, I understand the reasoning behind that. The orginal issue that I am having is that I have a report that is based on a query.  The query was written using parameters. When I call the report in VBA, is there a way that I can set the [ComplianceDate] parameter?

I am using DoCmd to call my report.

DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewPreview, , Criteria, acHidden

Comment: Not that I know of. Why don't you change the report RecordSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revise the report's *RecordSource* query ...

```sql
PARAMETERS [ComplianceDate] DateTime;
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
Where myDate = [ComplianceDate]
```

Use [DoCmd.SetParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.setparameter) to supply a value for the parameter and then open your report ...

```vb
DoCmd.SetParameter "ComplianceDate", Forms![myForm]![myComboxValue]
DoCmd.OpenReport reportName
```